# tetrahedron volume given rectangular parallelepiped

Tags: geometry, 3d, volume, solid-geometry

Let $A$ be a rectangular parallelepiped with edges of lengths $15, 20, 30$. Let $B$ be a tetrahedron on four non-adjacent vertices of $A$ (i.e no two vertices of $B$ share a common edge of $A$). Compute the volume of $B$.

[This](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1223609147) site gives a way to calculate but there's gotta be a closed form elegant formula for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Let the rectangular parallelepiped measurements be $a,\,b,\,c$ then the mixed product of the three vectors is $6$ times the volume of the desired tetrahedron
$$V=\frac16\operatorname{abs}
\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
a&b&0\\
a&0&c\\
0&b&c
\end{array}
\right|=\frac13 abc$$
Thus the desired volume is $\frac13\cdot 15\cdot 20\cdot 30=3000$.

Comment: More simply (to my mind, anyway), each of the tetrahedra at the vertices $A', B, C', D$ has volume $\tfrac16abc,$ so the tetrahedron $AB'CD'$ has volume $abc - \frac23abc = \frac13abc.$ The question [Volume of a tetrahedron whose 4 faces are congruent](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2908390) is relevant, but has more detail than is needed here.